# Assign a part of a composite foreign key at runtime

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that references another class with a composite Id:

```
SingleIdClassMap(){
  Id(x=>x.Id);
  References(x=>CompositeIdClass);
}

CompositeIdClass(){
  CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.SingleIdClass).KeyReference(x => x.DynamicProperty);
}
```

Now this does not compile since in the `SingleIdClassMap`, there is no information about the `DynamicProperty`. I want this to be loaded from another class at runtime:

```
PropertyClass.Singleton.GetCurrentProperty();
```

Is there a way to tell NHibernate that it can retrieve the value for the second part of the composite key from `PropertyClass.GetCurrentProperty()`?

Comment: is `PropertyClass.Singleton.GetCurrentProperty();` static or does it change through the lifetime of the app

Comment: I would bet that what you want is hard (not impossible) to accomplish. Is this some kind of localization implementation? Then there are many easier alternatives

Comment: Yes it is. I have one table per entity that contains texts. Each line has a key to the entity and a language key. It was a demand to have one table per entity table.

Answer (score 0):

IMO a filter is easiest

```
EntityMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasMany(x => Texts)
        .KeyColumn("entity_id")
        .ApplyFilter("languageFilter", "language_id = :lid");
}

EntityTextClass()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.Entity, "entity_id")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.LanguageId);
}

// at beginning of request
session.EnableFilter("languageFilter").SetParameter(":lid", languageId);

var entity = session.Query<Entity>().Fetch(e => e.Texts).First();
string text = entity.Texts.First();  // could be a seperate property
```

or if you need all Texts (e.g. When reviewing/editing localization)

```
var entity = session.Query<Entity>().Fetch(e => e.Texts).First();
var allTexts = entity.Texts;
```